# How to use the pytezos.crypto.encoding.base58_encode function?

Tags: cryptography, python, encoding

i'm trying to use the pytezos.crypto.key library. But i miss something giving the Key object my public key as an argument. Here my code :

```
encoded_key=pytezos.crypto.encoding.base58_encode(bytearray(b'edpkvFujbm3Xiamfxceg4GbsUBHzvqLZQmZvddg7xcFFvFQBEjeHTp'),b"edpk")
pytezos.crypto.key.Key.from_encoded(encoded_key)
```

Any ideas please ?

I got this error but i followed all the instructions from the docs...

```
ValueError: Invalid encoding, prefix or length mismatch.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
from pytezos.crypto.key import Key

pk = Key.from_encoded_key('edpkvFujbm3Xiamfxceg4GbsUBHzvqLZQmZvddg7xcFFvFQBEjeHTp')
```